# How do I pass a specific object from a FlatList to a function so I could delete it from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a watchlist of bookings for movies and when I click on a button for one of the FlatList rendered components I'd like to pass the object to the delete function and then to remove it from Firestore. I'm kind of stuck on how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
const WatchList = () => {

  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const docRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [watched, setWatched] = useState(true);
  const [text, setText] = useState('Watched movies');
  const [filteredBookings, setFilteredBookings] = useState(bookings);
  const bookingsRef = collection(db, "booking");

  const [bookings, setBookings] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    getBookings();
  },[])

  const getUser = async () => {
    const snap = await getDoc(docRef)
    setUser({user, ...snap.data()})
  }

  const getBookings = async () => {
     const q = query(bookingsRef, where("users","array-contains",auth.currentUser.uid));
     const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
     const a = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {            
     a.push(doc.data());
  });
     setBookings(querySnapshot.docs);
    });
  }

const deleteBooking = (item) => {
    console.log(item.data.().title)
}

  return (
<View>
  <View>
    <Text>{text}</Text>
  </View>
  
  <FlatList
    data = {filteredBookings}
    numColumns = {1}

    renderItem  = {({item}) => (
      <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.data().movie}</Text>
        <Text>{item.data().day} - {item.data().showtime}</Text>
      </View>

      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {deleteBooking(item)}}>
          <Text>Delete</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>
    )}
  />
      </View>
  )
}

export default WatchList`
```

I've been trying to pass an item to display it in the console log to see if I got the right one first, but it's not working, so I'd really appreaciate some pointers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your delete button's onPress method which you have defined as deleteBooking() you will get index also. you can rewrite as deleteBooking(item,index). and now in your definition use splice method of array. e.g. **arrayName.splice(index,1)** this will delete the record of given index.
For your array it should be like **bookings.splice(index,1)**. Here 1 represents how many record you want to delete from given index.

Let me know doest it works for you or not.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I was wondering how I could send the Firestore ID from that item to the function so I could remove it from the database as well, not just the screen. I'm assuming this wouldn't work for it, right?

Comment: Yes it will not work to delete data from firestore. I am not well aware with firestore but you can fire a query in your delete method to remove the data from firestore.

Comment: I've figured it out myself, thank you!